# Global Variables saying it's not defined in a function

Tags: python, tkinter

im trying to take a global variable depending on the button a user presses (using Tkinter), I tried to set a global variable for multiple options but its saying that the global variable is not defined, sorry if this is explained badly the code is below:
The error is in here its saying the variable pricediff is not defined.

def FinalValue():

global Final

Final = pricediff

The buttons are linked to the options (either Price_Selection1 etc. )

```
def Price_Selection1():
    global price
    price = 'one'
        
def Price_Selection2():
    global price
    price = 'two'
      
def Price_Selection3():
    global price
    price  = 'three'    
        
def Price_Selection4():
    global price
    price  = 'four'

def Final_Build():
        global pricediff
        if price == 'one':
            pricediff == 1000
        
        elif price == 'two':

            pricediff == 2000
        
        elif price == 'three':

            pricediff == 3000
        
        elif price == 'four':

            pricediff == 4000

def FinalValue(): 
    global Final
    Final = pricediff 
    
    Output = Label(root, Final)
    Output.grid(row=700, column=5)
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is because your not calling the `Final_Build()` function where you define your `pricediff` variable:

```
def FinalValue(): 
   global Final
   Final_Build() # call the function to give a value to pricediff
   Final = pricediff 

   Output = Label(root, Final)
   Output.grid(row=700, column=5)
```

Hope this helps. Its hard to tell otherwise what's going on in your code without a Traceback error message.